# upstream nginx (reverse proxy to uWSGI) HTTP/1.1 header not received

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am facing a weird problem where the upstream nginx (which is reverse proxy to uWSGI - python) doesn't send the HTTP/1.1 header and all the headers are received inside the actual response data. This version of nginx is compiled by the jenkins build server.

To verify if its problem with nginx, I cross-compiled nginx for my arm platform out of the jenkins build server and it works fine.

Appreciate any guidance in debugging this problem. I can post nginx conf on request if anybody see need of it.

**setup**

```
nginx v1.6.2 <--------------------> nginx v1.6.2 <---------> Client
  (debian)                             (arm)
  |
uWSGI
```

Following is **non-working** curl output,

```
> GET /login.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.128.2:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
>
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 12:00:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
Connection: close
Location: http://192.168.13.2/

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The **working** curl output is as below,

```
> GET /login.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.128.2:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 11:58:17 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 160
< Location: http://192.168.128.2:8080/
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the provider build environment is using CFLAG `-Os -g -pipi` options. I confirmed its `s` in `-Os` which is not working. Options `-O -g -pipe` works. It looks like the `arm` compiler we are using can't really handle it very well or the `nginx` code needs fix. The software I verified are `nginx v1.6.2` and `nginx v1.10.3` in case anybody interested in digging in.